# How to extract bits from binary executable

Tags: binary, executable, cat

For a research project, I need to hash the "executable footprint" of an application.  I don't have an expansive knowledge-base on this particular area.
I've tried `cat bash` for example, and stdout prints gobbledygook.
How can I read an executable as normal ones and zeroes?

Comment: An executable doesn't contain "normal ones and zeroes" (which is called `binary`, BTW). You have to read individual bytes (8 bits on modern OSes) and convert them to a binary representation for human eyes. An executable isn't "readable" like a book or a text file.

Comment: Take a look at `uuencode`, which might give you a more manageable representation (i.e. plain text) of your binary files. Of course, whether this is useful depends on what you mean by "executable footprint".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the binary representation as bits from a file you can use the following python script calling it using `python to_binary.py name_of_file`

```
import sys

def bin(x):
    return "".join(x & (1 << i) and "1" or "0" for i in range(7,-1,-1)) 

file = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
contents = file.read()
file.close()

for byte in contents:
    sys.stdout.write(bin(ord(byte)))
sys.stdout.write("\n")
```

Comment: I tried your code, and it seems to work correctly, though I can't be sure, of course.  Would I be correct in assuming that this script will return the same binary sequence each time it is run on the same file and that each executable will return a different one?

Comment: Yes, the code generates the bit stream for the file. For different file contents a different stream is generated.